# Follow up: Python class for Facebook

Tags: python, object-oriented, facebook

This is a follow-up [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49386/python-class-for-facebook)

I have taken some of the suggestions there and have made some changes from my side too. I think it looks better, but please look at it and lemme know if you think any more changes needs to be done.

It follows PEP8 standards.

```
__author = "Pranav Raj"
__email = "pranav09032@hotmail.com"

import simplejson as json
import urllib


class Facebook ():

 def __init__(self, accessToken):

    self.accessToken = accessToken
    self.id = None
    self.name = None
    self.baseUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/"

def urlRead(self, url):

    try:
        response = self.urlRead(url)
        return response
    except ConnectionError:
        raise Exception("Connection Exception")

def readTag(self, user, tag=""):

    return json.load(
        self.urlRead(
            self.baseUrl
            + "/" + tag + "?"
            + urllib.urlencode(
                dict(accessToken=
                     self.accessToken))))

def userInformation(self, fbUser="me"):

    profile = self.readTag(fbUser, "")
    self.id = profile.get("id", None)
    self.name = profile.get("name", None)
    if self.id and self.name:
        user = dict(key_name=str(profile["id"]),
                    id=str(profile["id"]),
                    name=profile["name"],
                    accessToken=self.accessToken,
                    profile_url=profile.get("link", None))
        return user
    raise Exception("Profile id or name is None")

def getFriends(self, maxParsedPages=4, fbUser="me"):

    friendsInfo = self.readTag(fbUser, "friends")
    friends = []
    for pages in range(maxParsedPages):
        paging = friendsInfo.get("paging", None)
        if not paging:
            raise Exception("Paging Error")
        if "next" in paging:
            friends += friendsInfo.get("userWall", [])
            friendsInfo = json.load(self.urlRead(paging["next"]))
        else:
            break
    return friends

def getUserWall(self, maxParsedPages=2, fbUser="me"):

    userFeeds = self.readTag(fbUser, "feed")
    userWall = []
    for pages in range(maxParsedPages):
        feed = userFeeds.get("userWall", None)
        if not feed:
            break
        userWall += feed
        paging = userFeeds.get("paging", None)
        if not paging:
            break
        nextUrl = paging.get("next", None)
        if not nextUrl:
            break
        userFeeds = json.load(
            self.urlRead(
                nextUrl))
    return userWall

def __getUserComment(self, fbUser, tag):

    UserWall = self.getUserWall(fbUser=fbUser)
    return [feed[tag] for feed in UserWall if tag in feed]

def getUserCommentsStory(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "story")

def getUserCommentsPicture(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "picture")

def getUserCommentsFrom(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "from")

def getUserCommentsName(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "name")

def getUserCommentsCaption(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "caption")

def getUserCommentsDescription(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "description")

def getUserCommentsComments(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "comments")

def getUserCommentsUpdatedTime(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "updated_time")

def getUserCommentsType(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "type")

def getUserCommentsId(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "id")

def getUserCommentsLikes(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserComment(fbUser, "likes")

def __getUserInfo(self, fbUser, fbProperty,
                  maxParsedPages=4, fbPropertyTag="name"):

    userRawProperty = self.readTag(fbUser, fbProperty)
    userProperty = []
    for pages in range(maxParsedPages):
        userProperty += [obj[fbPropertyTag]
                         for obj in userRawProperty["data"]]
        paging = userRawProperty.get("paging", None)
        if not paging:
            break
        nextUrl = paging.get("next", None)
        if not nextUrl:
            break
        userRawProperty = json.load(
            self.urlRead(
                nextUrl))
    return userProperty

def getUserLikes(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "likes")

def getUserMovies(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "movies")

def getUserMusic(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "music")

def getUserBooks(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "books")

def getUserNotes(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "notes")

def getUserPhotos(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "photos")

def getUserEvents(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "events")

def get_user_groups(self, fbUser="me"):

    return self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "groups")

def getUserPlaces(self, fbUser="me"):

    rawPlaceData = self.__getUserInfo(
        fbUser,
        "locations",
        fbPropertyTag="place")
    rawPlaceData = [place["name"] for place in rawPlaceData]
    placeData = {place: rawPlaceData.count(place)
                 for place in rawPlaceData}
    return placeData
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better! I can point out mostly style issues:

I would drop intermediate variables in simple statements like this:

> ```
> try:
>     response = self.urlRead(url)
>     return response
> ```

and do simply:

```
try:
    return self.urlRead(url)
```

---

I see you raise several generic `Exception("some message")` kind of exceptions. It might be better to create your own specialized Exception classes so that the calling code could distinguish the different kind of Exceptions. It depends on how you will use this code, and this might be overkill, so it's up to you.

---

You can simplify these kind of statements:

> ```
> paging = friendsInfo.get("paging", None)
> ```

you can drop `None` as the default value, because that's the default anyway:

```
paging = friendsInfo.get("paging")
```

---

Similarly, since the default tag is `""` in your `readTag` method, you could simplify this:

> ```
> profile = self.readTag(fbUser, "")
> ```

to simply:

```
profile = self.readTag(fbUser)
```

---

In this and another loop, I don't see the loop variable `pages` used at all:

> ```
> for pages in range(maxParsedPages):
>     feed = userFeeds.get("userWall", None)
>     ...
> ```

It might not be an official standard but I like to replace these with `_`:

```
for _ in range(maxParsedPages):
    feed = userFeeds.get("userWall", None)
    ...
```

---

Many times you break very simple statements to multiple lines:

> ```
> return self.__getUserInfo(
>     fbUser,
>     "likes")
> ```

In short statements like this that would easily stay within the 70-char limit of PEP8 I find it more natural and easier to read this way:

```
return self.__getUserInfo(fbUser, "likes")
```